# responsive content: prevent from downloading contents with css code: display: none !important on mobile browsers?

Tags: responsive-design

I wonder how the CSS declaration:

```
display: none !important;
```

will be treated by mobile browsers regarding to contents delivery.

Is it used to prevent mobile browsers (Android, iOS, etc...) from downloading content.

The declaration is used by frameworks such as foundation3 to hide content from devices when it should not be applied.

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

'Display: none' wil only hide your content. Unfortunately, the assets will still be downloaded. See this detailed list using 'display: none' to hide images and how various browsers react. http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

As for textual content, as far as I can tell, being part of the document, it will be read by the browser and hence downloaded.

You can see this for yourselves by opening your browser's inspector and looking at the network tab while the page is being downloaded. Every asset that is downloaded along with the duration it took to download is shown. Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with various object like images, a block of text, an empty div with background image etc. with 'display: none' applied to them all. Then refresh the page and observe the network tab and you'll see what is being downloaded.

It is not a very good idea to hide content with 'display: none' on mobiles, you can Conditionally load content via ajax and Jquery. I'd suggest looking into that.

Comment: According to your link, `display:none` works fine on condition that images are set via css (i.e., `background-image`).